# Entity Framework Linq many to many relation not included in select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have following entities:

```
public class EmployeeCv : UserEntity
{
        public byte ProfileImage { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Header> Headers { get; set; }
        [Index]
        public virtual List<ProjectExperience> ProjectExperiences { get; set; }
        [Index]
        public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : AuditableEntity<int>
{
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual List<EmployeeCv> EmployeeCv { get; set; }

        public virtual TagType TagType { get; set; }
}

public class TagType : AuditableEntity<int>
{
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string CssClass { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I have created DTO classes that just inherit the actual `EmployeeCv` and `Employee` class because Entity Framework was not allowing me to use the same classes in select.

```
public class EmployeeCvDTO : EmployeeCv
{
}

public class EmployeeDTO : Employee
{
}
```

My LINQ query:

```
var listOfEmployeeCV = from cvs in _context.EmployeeCvs.Include(x => x.Employee).Include(x => x.Tags).Include(x => x.Tags.Select(y => y.TagType))
                                   .Include(x => x.ProjectExperiences)
                                   where
                              _context.Employees.Any(
                                    e => e.FirstName.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)
                                    && e.Id == cvs.Id
                              ) || (_context.Tags.Any(t => t.Title.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) && cvs.Tags.Contains(t)))
                                || (_context.ProjectExperiences.Any(pe => (pe.ProjectTitle.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)
                                || pe.Description.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)) &&
                                cvs.ProjectExperiences.Contains(pe)))
                                   select new
                                   EmployeeCvDTO
                                   {
                                       Employee = new EmployeeDTO
                                       {
                                           FirstName = cvs.Employee.FirstName,
                                           LastName = cvs.Employee.LastName,
                                           EnterpriseId = cvs.Employee.EnterpriseId,
                                           Level = cvs.Employee.Level
                                           //ProfileImageData = x.Employee.ProfileImageData
                                       },
                                       Tags = cvs.Tags,

                                       ProjectExperiences = cvs.ProjectExperiences,
                               };
```

The above query works exactly as I want to. But the `listOfEmployeeCV.Tags.TagType` is null for all the tags. Even though I have included it in the `.include` statement but `EmployeeCv -> Tags -> TagType` is always null.

`EmployeeCv` and `Tags` have a many-to-many relationship, whereas `Tags` and `TagType` have a one-to-many relationship.
Also to add the below LINQ works fine and returns tagType as well:

```
var lista = from cvs in _context.EmployeeCvs.Include(x => x.Employee).Include(x => x.Tags).Include(x => x.Tags.Select(y => y.TagType))
                                   .Include(x => x.ProjectExperiences) select cvs;
var listb = lista.ToList();
```

Comment: We need to see your mappings, do you have the relationship mapped properly?

Comment: Relationships are mapped correctly. Below Linq works completely fine and returns TagType as well:

  var lista = from cvs in _context.EmployeeCvs.Include(x => x.Employee).Include(x => x.Tags).Include(x => x.Tags.Select(y => y.TagType))
                                   .Include(x => x.ProjectExperiences) select cvs;
            var listb = lista.ToList();

listb has got all the mapping right.